# SQL Server - Insert Rows in another table based on complex matching conditions (includes FIFO)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a complex problem - Bill Marking for Ageing Analysis. The data is like this :

Source Table :

```
TrxnID, Date, CustomerID, DebitCredit, Amount 
-----------------------------------------------
D1      01-Apr, RAS12,        D,        2000 
D2      01-Apr, RAS12,        D,        3000
C3      02-Apr, RAS12,        C,        4000
D4      03-Apr, RAS12,        D,        5000
C5      04-Apr, RAS12,        C,        1000
C6      10-Apr, RAS12,        C,        6000
D7      25-Apr, RAS12,        D,        3000
```

So, Total Debit : 13,000 and Total Credit : 11,000 and Total Balance is 2,000 Debit.

So the objective is to mark all Credit records with the respective debit records based on the date (FIFO), and store the marking scheme for each record in a separate table as shown below.

The target table has marking detail of each record

Target Table

```
TrxnID, MarkedTrxnID, MarkedAmount
------------------------------------    
d1,c3,2000 **Rem : D1 balance=0, c3 balance= 1000
d2,c3,2000 **Rem : D2 balance=1000, c3 balance= 0
d2,c5,1000 **Rem : D2 balance=0, c5 balance= 0
d4,c6,5000 **Rem : D4 balance=0, c6 balance= 1000
d7,c6,1000 **Rem : D7 balance=2000, c6 balance= 0
```

I have been using old fashioned cursor based approach and that too becomes quite complex, but believe that there must be a set based mechanism to handle this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. We are using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but probably it will have to be tested using more data than the 7 given rows.

1. First cross join the source table with itself. This will give all combinatiuons of the debet and the credit rows (7 * 7 = 49). Then select only the debet rows from the first source table and the credit rows from the second source table. We have 4 debet rows and 3 credit rows so this results in an output table of 12 rows. Each debet row will be linked to 3 credit rows. Add a running total of the credited amounts per debet transaction id (the column "Available" in my demo code). Add a column with the sum of all previous debet amounts (sum the debet amounts of all rows with a lower debet transaction id). This column I named "UsedBefore". Subtract "UsedBefore" from "Available" giving "Remains". Then subtract the current debet amount from "Remains" giving "RemainsAfter"
2. Use this table as input for a second select. Now only select rows with "Remains" greater than 0. Add a column with the amount "Paid". If "Remains" is greater than the debet amount this will be the debet amount and otherwise the "Remains" amount. Add a row_number that numbers the rows in each debet transacton id group.
3. Use the resulting table as input for the third select. Now only select the rows with a row_number equal to 1 or with an amount "RemainsAfter" less or equal to 0. You now have the rows you want but not yet the right amount credited.
4. Use the result of the previous selection as input for the fouth selection. Add a column "PaidNow". This is the amount "Paid" minus the previous amounts paid within the same debet transaction id group.

Try this:

```
select tab3.DebetTrnxID
, tab3.CreditTrnxID
, paid - sum(paid) over (partition by debetTrnxID order by rn) + paid as PaidNow
from (
    select * from (
        select * 
        , row_number() over (partition by tab.DebetTrnxID order by tab.CreditDate, tab.CreditTrnxID) as rn
        , case when remains >= debetamount then 
            DebetAmount
        else    
            Remains
        end as Paid
        from (
            select a.TrnxID as DebetTrnxID
            , a.Date as DebetDate
            , a.DebitCredit as DebetDebetCredit
            , a.Amount as DebetAmount
            , b.TrnxID as CreditTrnxID 
            , b.Date as CreditDate
            , b.DebitCredit as CreditDebetCredit
            , b.Amount as CreditAmount
            , sum(b.amount) over (partition by a.trnxid order by a.Date, a.TrnxId, b.Date, b.TrnxID) as Available
            , isnull((select sum(c.amount) from source c where c.DebitCredit='D' and c.TrnxID<a.TrnxID),0) as UsedBefore
            ,  sum(b.amount) over (partition by a.trnxid order by a.Date, a.TrnxId, b.Date, b.TrnxID) 
            - isnull((select sum(c.amount) from source c where c.DebitCredit='D' and c.TrnxID<a.TrnxID),0) as Remains
            ,  sum(b.amount) over (partition by a.trnxid order by a.Date, a.TrnxId, b.Date, b.TrnxID) 
            - isnull((select sum(c.amount) from source c where c.DebitCredit='D' and c.TrnxID<a.TrnxID),0) 
            - a.amount as RemainsAfter

            from source a
            cross join source b

            where a.DebitCredit='D'
            and b.DebitCredit='C'
            ) tab
        where remains>0
        ) tab2
    where tab2.rn=1
    or tab2.RemainsAfter<=0
    ) tab3
order by tab3.DebetTrnxID
, tab3.CreditTrnxID
```

Albert

Comment: Thank you Albert, will check and revert.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue using cursors only. Here are the steps followed :

1. Create a cursor with Sum of Debit and Sum of Credit, grouped by Customers - so this gives me a list of Customers for whom the Adjustment is to be run
2. Start a Loop
3. Create separate cursors for Debit & Credit Individual Records for that customer
4. Run through loop sequentially putting proper logic and ensuring that debit and credit records are correctly matched - any matching records gets inserted into the separate table. It was more of a logical flow issue then technical issue to ensure that only the desired cursor (either debit or credit or both) move to next record, and only the balance amount are matched.
5. The whole procedure ran in less than 4 minutes for more than 600,000 records, which is very much acceptable
6. Conclusion : sometimes cursor based operations are faster then set based operations

   ```
   --step 1 
   select cv.customercode,sum(case when cv.drcr='D' then cv.Amount else 0
    end) as PendAmountDr, 
       sum(case when cv.drcr='C' then cv.Amount else 0 end) as PendAmountCr               
      From SourceTable cv              
   Group by cv.CustomerCode 
   having sum(case when cv.drcr='D' then cv.Amount else 0 end) <> 0 
       and sum(case when cv.drcr='C' then cv.Amount else 0 end) <> 0 
   --Use Fetch Commands & While Loop  
   --STEP 2 : Create Cursor for Debit Records for that customer order by date
   While @@Fetch_Status = 0
      DECLARE CVDR CURSOR READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR                            
               select TRANSACTIONID, cv.Amount                                    
               From Cashvchr cv              
               where  cv.CompanyID=@CompanyID and isnull(cv.deleted,0) = 0 
               AND isnull(cv.CustomerCode,'') = @Cust 
               AND CV.DRCR = 'D' 
               ORDER BY VCHRDATE,TRANSACTIONID
   --STEP 3 : Create Cursor for Credit Records for that customer order by date
   DECLARE CVCR CURSOR READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR                            
               select TRANSACTIONID, cv.Amount                                    
               From Cashvchr cv              
               where  cv.CompanyID=@CompanyID and isnull(cv.deleted,0) = 0 
               AND isnull(cv.CustomerCode,'') = @Cust 
               AND CV.DRCR = 'C' 
               ORDER BY VCHRDATE,TRANSACTIONID

           set @Balamtdr = @amtdr 
           set @balamtcr = @amtcr

           WHILE @AMTTOMARK > 0 
               BEGIN                   

                   SET @CVID = @CVIDDR 
                   SET @MCVID = @CVIDCR
                   SET @CURRMARKAMT=0
                   set @skipdr = 0
                   set @skipcr = 0
                   IF @BALAMTDR > @BALAMTCR  -- i.e. balance debit amount to be marked is bigger from bal.credit amt THEN skip CREDIT
                       begin 
                           SET @CURRMARKAMT = @balAMTCR                                    
                           set @skipCr = 1
                           set @balamtdr = @balamtdr - @balamtcr 
                       end
                   ELSE IF @balAMTDR < @balAMTCR -- i.e. balance Credit amount is bigger THEN skip Debit
                       begin 
                           SET @CURRMARKAMT = @balAMTDR    
                           set @skipdr  = 1
                           set @balamtcr = @balamtCr - @balamtdr 
                       end
                   ELSE -- i.e. balance Credit & Debit amount is same, mark and skip both 
                       begin 
                           SET @CURRMARKAMT = @balamtdr
                           set @balamtcr = @balamtCr - @balamtdr 
                           set @skipdr = 1
                           set @skipcr = 1
                       end
                   ----
                   INSERT INTO TargetTable 
                       (CASHVCHRID,AMOUNT,MARKEDCASHVCHRID)                        VALUES 
                       (@CVIDDR,@CURRMARKAMT,@CVIDCR) 

                   set @amttomark = @amttomark - @currmarkamt 

                   if @skipdr = 1 and @amttomark > 0 
                       begin 
                           FETCH next from CVDR INTO @CVIDDR, @AMTDR
                           if @@fetch_status <> 0
                               begin
                                   set @amttomark = 0 -- no further marking possible some problem, should exit
                               end
                           else
                               begin
                                   set @balamtdr = @amtdr
                               end
                           -- end if 
                       end
                   -- end if @skipdr = 1 
                   if @skipcr = 1 and @amttomark > 0 
                       begin 
                           FETCH next from CVCR INTO @CVIDCR, @AMTCR   
                           if @@fetch_status <> 0
                               begin
                                   set @amttomark = 0 -- no further marking possible some problem, should exit
                               end
                           else
                               begin
                                   set @balamtcr = @amtcr
                               end
                           -- end if 

                       end
                   -- end if @skipcr = 1 
               END
           -- END WHILE @AMTTOMARK > 0 FOR DR/CR skip FOR ONE CUSTOMER
   ```